# Populating CartesianChart Label with column from SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, charts, livecharts

I have a `CartesianChart` and I am able to populate `SeriesCollection` (y-axis) with the values from my database. However, I seem to be struggling with populating the (x-axis) `Labels`.

I have an SQL Server query that returns a table with 3 columns in which the first column shows the `MonthValue` and the other two are `Average` that is named `SmallCommercialIndust_avg` and `Residential_avg`

In my chart, the (y-axis) is populated with the `Averages` columns I would like to populate (x-axis) `Labels` with the values from the `MonthValue` column. However, I am not sure how I can do that. I have only been able to `HardCode` the months which doesn't work with my query.

Here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    DATENAME(MONTH, hb_Disputes.DATERSLVD) AS MonthValue, 
    AVG(CASE 
           WHEN hb_Disputes.ASSGNTO = 'E099255' AND hb_Disputes.REV_CLS = 1 
              THEN DATEDIFF(day, hb_Disputes.OPENED, hb_Disputes.DATERSLVD) 
              ELSE 0  
        END) AS SmallCommercialIndust_avg, 
    AVG(CASE 
           WHEN hb_Disputes.ASSGNTO = 'E099255' AND hb_Disputes.REV_CLS = 2 
              THEN DATEDIFF(day, hb_Disputes.OPENED, hb_Disputes.DATERSLVD) 
              ELSE 0 
        END) AS Residential_avg
FROM 
    hb_RateType
INNER JOIN 
    hb_Disputes ON hb_RateType.RTID = hb_Disputes.REV_CLS 
WHERE 
    YEAR(hb_Disputes.DATERSLVD) = YEAR(GETDATE())
GROUP BY 
    DATENAME(MONTH, hb_Disputes.DATERSLVD)
ORDER BY 
    MIN(hb_Disputes.DATERSLVD)
```

Here is my the output:

```
MonthValue                     SmallCommercialIndust_avg Residential_avg 
------------------------------ ------------------------- ---------------
May                            0                         46
```

Here is my code for the `CartesianChart`:

```
namespace CaseManagementSystem
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for BasicRowChartHBD.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class BasicRowChartHBD : UserControl
    {
        public SeriesCollection SeriesCollection { get; set; }
        public string[] Labels { get; set; }
        public Func<double, string> Formatter { get; set; }

        public BasicRowChartHBD()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ChartValues();
        }

        private void ChartValues()
        {

            // Defines the variable for differnt lines.
            List<double> SmallCommercialIndustValues = new List<double>();
            List<double> ResidentialValues = new List<double>();


            try
            {
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=WINDOWS-B1AT5HC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CustomerRelations;Integrated Security=True;");

                string selectQuery = ("SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, d.OPENED) AS MonthValue, SUM(CASE WHEN d.ASSGNTO = 'E099255' AND d.REV_CLS = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SmallCommercialIndust, SUM(CASE WHEN d.ASSGNTO = 'E099255' AND d.REV_CLS <> 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Residential FROM hb_Disputes d WHERE YEAR(d.OPENED) = YEAR(GETDATE()) GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, d.OPENED) ORDER BY MIN(d.OPENED);");
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);

                SqlDataReader sqlReader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (sqlReader.Read())
                {
                    // Check for DBNull and then assign the variable
                    if (sqlReader["SmallCommercialIndust"] != DBNull.Value)
                        SmallCommercialIndustValues.Add(Convert.ToInt32(sqlReader["SmallCommercialIndust"]));

                    // Check for DBNull and then assign the variable
                    if (sqlReader["Residential"] != DBNull.Value)
                        ResidentialValues.Add(Convert.ToInt32(sqlReader["Residential"]));

                }
                // Starts new line series.
                SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
                {
                    new RowSeries
                    {
                        Title = "Residential",
                        Values = new ChartValues<double>(ResidentialValues),
                        DataContext = true,
                    },
                    new RowSeries
                    {
                        Title = "Small Commercial Indust",
                        Values = new ChartValues<double>(SmallCommercialIndustValues),
                        DataContext = true,
                    }
                };

                Labels = new []
                {
                    "Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"
                };
                Formatter = value => value.ToString("0");

                //Sets the graph X Value.
                //SeriesCollection[1].Values.Add(5d);


                DataContext = this;

                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }

        }
    }
}
```